# Message selector on MDBean not working properly

Tags: performance, message-driven-bean, ibm-was

I'm having a bit of a problem with an application, the message-selector of my MD Bean doesn't respond to the filter specified, if i use inside the message-selector : `module in ('TELCOM1')` works perfectly , but if i add a second parameter to the filter `(module in ('TELCOM1' , 'TELCOM2') )` it doesn't work at all, doesn't respond to either parameter.

Does anybody have an idea of why can this be , I'm running my application on a `WAS 8.5.5` but if i run it on`WAS 6` works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok .. doing some more work on why this was happening, i found that i was using WMQv6 with my WAS 8.5.5 , so i change it to WMQv7 and it work fine.