# Does WAS 8.5.5 support prior version of WMQ?

Tags: websphere, mq

I posted a question about a problem a was having with a EJB application i was migrating from WAS6 to WAS8.5.5, here is the link:

[Message selector on MDBean not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855266/message-selector-on-mdbean-not-working-properly/26893962#26893962)

And I found that a had a prior version of WMQ (v6), so i upgraded that version to v7 and my application worked.

My question is, isn't WAS 8.5.5 suppose to support prior version of WMQ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MQ Resource Adapter that is deployed within WAS 8.5.5 will be supported back to earlier verfsion of MQ. Full details are available here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/prodconn_1.0.0/com.ibm.scenarios.wmqwasusing.doc/topics/swg21498708_85.htm

Upgrading to WMQ v6 would be recommdened however as MQ v6 is not longer a supported version.